# Apple Books won't download any books/files saved in iCloud only on Mac (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: mac, icloud, books

I can't download any books/files I saved with iCloud in the Apple Books app on my Mac anymore (it worked before though). Books from the Apple Books store will download fine. I can also download all books saved in iCloud with iOS without problems.
There is no error message, instead the Download will apparently start as indicated in the sidebar:

[image: Books App Sidebar]

However, the download will never process at all (again, every other download works without issue).

Things I tried that didn't work:

- Rebooted the system
- Logged out and back in with the corresponding Apple account
- Disabled and reenabled syncing for Books in the iCloud settings
- Removed all `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.iBooksX.*` folders and rebooted
- Removed `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks` folder and rebooted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be related to the storage optimisation feature for iCloud (maybe it is somehow stuck or blocking these downloads). It can be found under `System Preferences -> Apple ID -> Optimise Mac Storage`. After turning the future off and on all downloads in Apple Books now work again.

Comment: I just came here to say you are wonderful. I discovered this bug 6 months ago, tried googling and debugging it in similar ways to your initial report and gave up. Came back to it today as I wanted to open a book on my Mac and found your query and resolution. Suffice to say, thank you so very very much!

Comment: Saved me tons of time. Was short of starting downloads manually...